# outlook fails pop3 ssl auth with courier and postfix

Tags: outlook, postfix-mta

first off, everything works fine with kontacts, but outlook is being a pain.
This is a fresh server with a new build following this method https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Complete_Virtual_Mail_Server
When using outlook and running test I get:

```
Aug 10 09:47:19 emailer1 pop3d-ssl: couriertls: /etc/ssl/certs/48ef30f1.0: No such file or directory
^C
emailer1 ~ # updatedb
emailer1 ~ # locate 48ef30f1
/etc/ssl/certs/48ef30f1.0
emailer1 ~ # ls -l /etc/ssl/
total 44
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root   4096 Aug  8 07:46 apache2
drwxr-xr-x 2 vmail vmail 12288 Aug  8 12:06 certs
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root   4096 Aug  9 04:01 courier-imap
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root   4096 Aug  8 12:05 misc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  10835 Aug  8 12:03 openssl.cnf
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root   4096 Aug 10 09:15 postfix
drwx------ 2 root  root   4096 Aug  8 12:05 private
emailer1 ~ #



emailer1 ~ # postconf -n
broken_sasl_auth_clients = no
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
home_mailbox = .maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_protocols = ipv4
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = no
sample_directory = /etc/postfix
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = no
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/postfix/nyctelecomm.com.crt
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/postfix/nyctelecomm.com.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/postfix/nyctelecomm.com.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 3
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

The permissions where root before.

```
emailer1 ~ # cat /etc/courier-imap/pop3d-ssl
##VERSION: $Id: pop3d-ssl.dist.in,v 1.22 2008/07/12 20:17:25 mrsam Exp $
#
# pop3d-ssl created from pop3d-ssl.dist by sysconftool
#
# Do not alter lines that begin with ##, they are used when upgrading
# this configuration.
#
#  Copyright 2000-2008 Double Precision, Inc.  See COPYING for
#  distribution information.
#
#  This configuration file sets various options for the Courier-IMAP server
#  when used to handle SSL POP3 connections.
#
#  SSL and non-SSL connections are handled by a dedicated instance of the
#  couriertcpd daemon.  If you are accepting both SSL and non-SSL POP3
#  connections, you will start two instances of couriertcpd, one on the
#  POP3 port 110, and another one on the POP3-SSL port 995.
#
#  Download OpenSSL from http://www.openssl.org/
#
##NAME: SSLPORT:0
#
#  Options in the pop3d-ssl configuration file AUGMENT the options in the
#  pop3d configuration file.  First the pop3d configuration file is read,
#  then the pop3d-ssl configuration file, so we do not have to redefine
#  anything.
#
#  However, some things do have to be redefined.  The port number is
#  specified by SSLPORT, instead of PORT.  The default port is port 995.
#
#  Multiple port numbers can be separated by commas.  When multiple port
#  numbers are used it is possibly to select a specific IP address for a
#  given port as "ip.port".  For example, "127.0.0.1.900,192.168.0.1.900"
#  accepts connections on port 900 on IP addresses 127.0.0.1 and 192.168.0.1
#  The SSLADDRESS setting is a default for ports that do not have
#  a specified IP address.

SSLPORT=995

##NAME: SSLADDRESS:0
#
#  Address to listen on, can be set to a single IP address.
#
# SSLADDRESS=127.0.0.1

SSLADDRESS=0

##NAME: SSLPIDFILE:0
#

SSLPIDFILE=/var/run/pop3d-ssl.pid

##NAME: SSLLOGGEROPTS:0
#
# courierlogger(1) options.
#

SSLLOGGEROPTS="-name=pop3d-ssl"

##NAME: POP3DSSLSTART:0
#
#  Whether or not to start POP3 over SSL on spop3 port:

POP3DSSLSTART=YES

##NAME: POP3_STARTTLS:0
#
# Whether or not to implement the POP3 STLS extension:

POP3_STARTTLS=YES

##NAME: POP3_TLS_REQUIRED:1
#
# Set POP3_TLS_REQUIRED to 1 if you REQUIRE STARTTLS for everyone.
# (this option advertises the LOGINDISABLED POP3 capability, until STARTTLS
# is issued).

POP3_TLS_REQUIRED=0

##NAME: COURIERTLS:0
#
# The following variables configure POP3 over SSL.  If OpenSSL or GnuTLS
# is available during configuration, the couriertls helper gets compiled, and
# upon installation a dummy TLS_CERTFILE gets generated.
#
# WARNING: Peer certificate verification has NOT yet been tested.  Proceed
# at your own risk.  Only the basic SSL/TLS functionality is known to be
# working. Keep this in mind as you play with the following variables.

COURIERTLS=/usr/sbin/couriertls

##NAME: TLS_PROTOCOL:0
#
# TLS_PROTOCOL sets the protocol version.  The possible versions are:
#
# OpenSSL:
#
# SSL2 - SSLv2
# SSL3 - SSLv3
# SSL23 - either SSLv2 or SSLv3 (also TLS1, it seems)
# TLS1 - TLS1
#
# Note that this setting, with OpenSSL, is modified by the TLS_CIPHER_LIST
# setting, below.
#
# GnuTLS:
#
# SSL3   - SSLv3
# TLS1   - TLS 1.0
# TLS1_1 - TLS 1.1
#
# When compiled against GnuTLS, multiple protocols can be selected as follows:
#
# TLS_PROTOCOL="TLS1_1:TLS1:SSL3"
#
# DEFAULT VALUES:
#
# SSL23 (OpenSSL), or "TLS_1:TLS1:SSL3" (GnuTLS)

##NAME: TLS_STARTTLS_PROTOCOL:0
#
# TLS_STARTTLS_PROTOCOL is used instead of TLS_PROTOCOL for the POP3 STARTTLS
# extension, as opposed to POP3 over SSL on port 995.
#
# It takes the same values for OpenSSL/GnuTLS as TLS_PROTOCOL

TLS_STARTTLS_PROTOCOL=TLS1

##NAME: TLS_CIPHER_LIST:0
#
# TLS_CIPHER_LIST optionally sets the list of ciphers to be used by the
# OpenSSL library.  In most situations you can leave TLS_CIPHER_LIST
# undefined
#
# OpenSSL:
#
# TLS_CIPHER_LIST="SSLv3:TLSv1:!SSLv2:HIGH:!LOW:!MEDIUM:!EXP:!NULL@STRENGTH"
#
# To enable SSL2, remove the obvious "!SSLv2" part from the above list.
#
#
# GnuTLS:
#
# TLS_CIPHER_LIST="HIGH:MEDIUM"
#
# The actual list of available ciphers depend on the options GnuTLS was
# compiled against. The possible ciphers are:
#
# AES256, 3DES, AES128, ARC128, ARC40, RC2, DES, NULL
#
# Also, the following aliases:
#
# HIGH -- all ciphers that use more than a 128 bit key size
# MEDIUM -- all ciphers that use a 128 bit key size
# LOW -- all ciphers that use fewer than a 128 bit key size, the NULL cipher
#        is not included
# ALL -- all ciphers except the NULL cipher


##NAME: TLS_MIN_DH_BITS:0
#
# TLS_MIN_DH_BITS=n
#
# GnuTLS only:
#
# Set the minimum number of acceptable bits for a DH key exchange.
#
# GnuTLS's compiled-in default is 727 bits (as of GnuTLS 1.6.3). Some server
# have been encountered that offer 512 bit keys. You may have to set
# TLS_MIN_DH_BITS=512 here, if necessary.

##NAME: TLS_KX_LIST:0
#
# GnuTLS only:
#
# Allowed key exchange protocols. The default of "ALL" should be sufficient.
# The list of supported key exchange protocols depends on the options GnuTLS
# was compiled against, but may include the following:
#
# DHERSA, DHEDSS, RSA, SRP, SRPRSA, SRPDSS, PSK, DHEPSK, ANONDH, RSAEXPORT

TLS_KX_LIST=ALL

##NAME: TLS_COMPRESSION:0
#
# GnuTLS only:
#
# Optional compression. "ALL" selects all available compression methods.
#
# Available compression methods: DEFLATE, LZO, NULL

TLS_COMPRESSION=ALL

##NAME: TLS_CERTS:0
#
# GnuTLS only:
#
# Supported certificate types are X509 and OPENPGP.
#
# OPENPGP has not been tested

TLS_CERTS=X509

##NAME: TLS_TIMEOUT:0
# TLS_TIMEOUT is currently not implemented, and reserved for future use.
# This is supposed to be an inactivity timeout, but its not yet implemented.
#

##NAME: TLS_DHCERTFILE:0
#
# TLS_DHCERTFILE - PEM file that stores a Diffie-Hellman -based certificate.
# When OpenSSL is compiled to use Diffie-Hellman ciphers instead of RSA
# you must generate a DH pair that will be used.  In most situations the
# DH pair is to be treated as confidential, and the file specified by
# TLS_DHCERTFILE must not be world-readable.
#
# TLS_DHCERTFILE=

##NAME: TLS_CERTFILE:0
#
# TLS_CERTFILE - certificate to use.  TLS_CERTFILE is required for SSL/TLS
# servers, and is optional for SSL/TLS clients.  TLS_CERTFILE is usually
# treated as confidential, and must not be world-readable. Set TLS_CERTFILE
# instead of TLS_DHCERTFILE if this is a garden-variety certificate
#
# VIRTUAL HOSTS (servers only):
#
# Due to technical limitations in the original SSL/TLS protocol, a dedicated
# IP address is required for each virtual host certificate. If you have
# multiple certificates, install each certificate file as
# $TLS_CERTFILE.aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd, where "aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd" is the IP address
# for the certificate's domain name. So, if TLS_CERTFILE is set to
# /etc/certificate.pem, then you'll need to install the actual certificate
# files as /etc/certificate.pem.192.168.0.2, /etc/certificate.pem.192.168.0.3
# and so on, for each IP address.
#
# GnuTLS only (servers only):
#
# GnuTLS implements a new TLS extension that eliminates the need to have a
# dedicated IP address for each SSL/TLS domain name. Install each certificate
# as $TLS_CERTFILE.domain, so if TLS_CERTFILE is set to /etc/certificate.pem,
# then you'll need to install the actual certificate files as
# /etc/certificate.pem.host1.example.com, /etc/certificate.pem.host2.example.com
# and so on.
#
# Note that this TLS extension also requires a corresponding support in the
# client. Older SSL/TLS clients may not support this feature.
#
# This is an experimental feature.

TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/ssl/postfix/nyctelecomm.com.pem

##NAME: TLS_TRUSTCERTS:0
#
# TLS_TRUSTCERTS=pathname - load trusted certificates from pathname.
# pathname can be a file or a directory. If a file, the file should
# contain a list of trusted certificates, in PEM format. If a
# directory, the directory should contain the trusted certificates,
# in PEM format, one per file and hashed using OpenSSL's c_rehash
# script. TLS_TRUSTCERTS is used by SSL/TLS clients (by specifying
# the -domain option) and by SSL/TLS servers (TLS_VERIFYPEER is set
# to PEER or REQUIREPEER).
#

TLS_TRUSTCERTS=/etc/ssl/certs

##NAME: TLS_VERIFYPEER:0
#
# TLS_VERIFYPEER - how to verify client certificates.  The possible values of
# this setting are:
#
# NONE - do not verify anything
#
# PEER - verify the client certificate, if one's presented
#
# REQUIREPEER - require a client certificate, fail if one's not presented
#
#
TLS_VERIFYPEER=NONE

##NAME: TLS_EXTERNAL:0
#
# To enable SSL certificate-based authentication:
#
# 1) TLS_TRUSTCERTS must be set to a pathname that holds your certificate
#    authority's SSL certificate
#
# 2) TLS_VERIFYPEER=PEER or TLS_VERIFYPEER=REQUIREPEER (the later settings
#    requires all SSL clients to present a certificate, and rejects
#    SSL/TLS connections without a valid cert).
#
# 3) Set TLS_EXTERNAL, below, to the subject field that holds the login ID.
#    Example:
#
#  TLS_EXTERNAL=emailaddress
#
# The above example retrieves the login ID from the "emailaddress" subject
# field. The certificate's emailaddress subject must match exactly the login
# ID in the courier-authlib database.

##NAME: TLS_CACHE:0
#
# A TLS/SSL session cache may slightly improve response for long-running
# POP3 clients. TLS_CACHEFILE will be automatically created, TLS_CACHESIZE
# bytes long, and used as a cache buffer.
#
# This is an experimental feature and should be disabled if it causes
# problems with SSL clients.  Disable SSL caching by commenting out the
# following settings:

TLS_CACHEFILE=/var/lib/courier-imap/couriersslcache
TLS_CACHESIZE=524288

##NAME: MAILDIRPATH:0
#
# MAILDIRPATH - directory name of the maildir directory.
#
MAILDIRPATH=Maildir

# Hardwire a value for ${MAILDIR}
MAILDIR=.maildir
MAILDIRPATH=.maildir
```

Comment: permissions on the dir are now 770, same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue happened to be on both outlook and kontacts, I just wasn't digging deep enough.
since the OS is gentoo, I re emerged ca-certificates and deleted all of the broken links (as specified by emerge) and now everything is 100%